# Using a class reference to define a variable

Tags: java

I have the following enum:

```
public enum Registry {

  Test(A.class);
  private final Class<? extends Alphabet> letter;

  Registry(Class<? extends Alphabet> letter) {
      this.letter = letter
  }

  public Class<? extends Alphabet> getLetter() {
      return form;
  }
}
```

I want to use the enum to pass into the construction of another class, something like this:

```
public final class ServiceCreator {

   private final Registry registry;

   public ServiceCreator(Registry registry) {
       this.registry = registry;
   }

   public Service<registry.getLetter()> createService() {
       return new Service<registry.getLetter()>();
   }

   public final class Service<Letter extends Alphabet> {
       private Service(){}
   }
}
```

The idea is that I can use a dynamic class definition to define the generic based of off what is saved in the enum. I have tested this code and it obviously doesn't work, I want to know whether I am doing it wrong or if the approach is wrong. If the approach is wrong, how could I make it work? The class that is called "service" has to be a generic.

Comment: I think you're trying to create a factory pattern? This isn't how generics work in Java, though--how would the compiler know at compile time what's in `registry`?

Comment: What is `Test(A.class);`?

Comment: A.class is a random class which extends Alphabet